# template function overloading ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates

A beginner's question here, so I have the following code

`foo.h`

```cpp
enum class Fruit : uint16_t {
    Apple  = 8019U,
    Orange = 8020U,
    Banana = 8021U,
    Cactus = 8022U
};

class Foo {
  public:
    template<typename T> void SetValue(unsigned int location, const T& value);
    template<typename T> void SetValue(unsigned int location, const T* value_ptr);
    template<typename T> void SetValue(Fruit fruit, const T& value);
    template<typename T> void SetValue(Fruit fruit, const T* value_ptr);
}
```

`foo.cpp`

```cpp
template<typename T>
void Foo::SetValue(unsigned int location, const T& value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Foo::SetValue(unsigned int location, const T* value_ptr) {
    std::cout << (*value_ptr) << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Foo::SetValue(Fruit fruit, const T& value) {
    SetValue<T>(static_cast<unsigned int>(fruit), value);
}

template<typename T>
void Foo::SetValue(Fruit fruit, const T* value_ptr) {
    SetValue<T>(static_cast<unsigned int>(fruit), value_ptr);
}

#define INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(T) \
    template void Foo::SetValue<T>(unsigned int location, const T& value); \
    template void Foo::SetValue<T>(unsigned int location, const T* value_ptr); \
    template void Foo::SetValue<T>(Fruit fruit, const T& value); \
    template void Foo::SetValue<T>(Fruit fruit, const T* value_ptr);

INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(int)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(uint)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(bool)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(float)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(vec2)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(vec3)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(vec4)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(mat2)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(mat3)
INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(mat4)
...

#undef INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
int main() {
    Foo foo;

    float bar[7] { 0.0f, 0.15f, 0.3f, 0.45f, 0.6f, 0.75f, 0.9f };
    float baz = 12.5f;

    foo.SetValue(Fruit::Orange, 1.05);  // calling SetValue<double>(Fruit fruit, const double& value)

    foo.SetValue(Fruit::Apple, bar + 3);  // calling SetValue<float*>(Fruit fruit, float *const& value)
    foo.SetValue(Fruit::Cactus, &baz);    // calling SetValue<float*>(Fruit fruit, float *const& value)
}
```

In the last 2 calls, while I really intended to call
`SetValue<float>(Fruit fruit, const float* value_ptr)`

What actually gets called are
`SetValue<float*>(Fruit fruit, float *const& value)`

I'm aware that this is ambiguous because VS Intellisense was not able to color highlight `SetValue<T>` in the overridden function body, so I tried to write `foo.SetValue<float>(Fruit::Cactus, &baz)` instead, now the compiler interprets `T` as `float` rather than `float*`, but I wonder if this is a horrible design...... Is there a better approach that doesn't require me to explicitly specify the type of `T`? How can I eliminate the ambiguity completely?

Comment: You could play with SFINAE, but... just use different names for functions taking values and pointers.

Comment: As to "horrible design": do you really need to have both overloads, for pointers and for references? Would it be so bad to have an extra `*` or `&` at some call sites?

Comment: [OT]: See [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: @Thomas Hmm, I think you are right, maybe I just need the `const T&` version, but if `T` is a pointer type, my function wants to bind to it and observe changes automatically, is there a way I can tell if `T` is a pointer?

Comment: Difference in behaviour depending on whether you pass a pointer or a reference? That's _definitely_ smelly design in my opinion. Maybe name the pointer-accepting version `BindValue` or `WatchValue` or something like that, instead of `SetValue`.

Comment: @Thomas, Yes I agree, I should get rid of the pointer version by including another parameter `bool bind`, much clearer to read.

Comment: If we're having a design discussion anyway: I stand by my recommendation of having a _differently named_ function. How does a reader know what the `true` means in `SetValue(Fruit::Cactus, &baz, true)`? Whereas with `BindValue(Fruit::Cactus, &baz)` it's much clearer.

Comment: @Thomas, you're right, speaking of readability I'll surely take your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm aware that this is ambiguous

It is not.

`const T& value` is a better match than `const T* value` for `float*`.
The former is an exact match, whereas the later require a [qualification conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Qualification_conversions).

You might drop the `const` for pointer:

```
template<typename T> void SetValue(Fruit fruit, T* value_ptr);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f97545cc389b46ab)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this topic is so advanced to me... I'll study it.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want do use SFINAE.

```
 template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, bool> = false> 
// no difference between = true or = false
 void SetValue(unsigned int location, const T& value) {
         std::cout << value << std::endl;
 }

 template<typename T>
 void SetValue(unsigned int location, const T* value_ptr) {
         std::cout << (*value_ptr) << std::endl;
 }
```

Just use this to replace the above 2 functions(the ones which cout). I don't think the 4th function(`Fruit fruit, const T* value_ptr`) is necessary.

Comment: Very nice solution~ but SFINAE seems really ugly to me...

Comment: @neo-mashiro SFINAE itself is not ugly, but the interface that could easily bewilder a code reader is. These two `setValue` functions do different things and have different semantics. They should not have the same name.

Comment: SFINAE might be replaced by concept/constraint (C++20), which has better syntax: `template<typename T> requires(!std::is_pointer<T>::value) void SetValue(unsigned int location, const T& value)`.

Comment: *"I don't really know if there is a difference between `= true` or `= false`"*. There is none in that context.

Comment: @Jarod42, I guessed that but wasn't sure!